# How can I use SCSS color functions to emulate a white transparent overlay?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to use SCSS to fake a white transparent color overlaying another solid color. I could easily do `background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.5)` on the overlay `<div>`, but I'd rather have a solution that doesn't require the browser to support rgba colors. Also, since I'm using SCSS variables, I won't necessarily know what the bottom color is beforehand, so I'll need to calculate the result.

It seems like one of the [SCSS color functions](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#scale_color-instance_method) should be able to achieve this effect, but I've tried a few things, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's a demo to better illustrate what I'm trying to do, or you can see the code pasted below.
http://jsfiddle.net/BRKR3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="overlay rgba"></div>
</div>

<div class="background">
    <div class="overlay scss"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$background: #009966;

.background {
    background-color:$background;
    height:60px;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
    width:60px;
}

.overlay {
   height:60px;
   width:60px;
}

.rgba {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

/* works if $background is $808080, but not if it's a color */
.scss {
    background-color:scale-color($background, $lightness:150%);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a working jsFiddle using Chuck's answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/BRKR3/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lightness doesn't blend a color with white; it makes it a lighter color, which means it's lighter but the components are also more intense (whereas blending with white makes them more muted). You can think of lightness as multiplying the color. In order to get a screen effect when you adjust lightness, you need to decrease the saturation proportionately.

To get the effect you want, just use `mix($background, white, 50%)`. This performs the same kind of blending that compositing colors with alpha does.

Comment: Thanks Chuck! This is exactly what I was looking for. I also discovered that I could do the same thing with manual color arithmetic like so: `$color + (white - $color) / 2` but I'm glad to find that there's a function that does the same thing.

Comment: +1 for explanation. I found a very usefull website which lets you adjust the color visually at [colorme.io](https://colorme.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont' see how changing the lightness would be like faking a white transparent overlay. Also, I don't think you can achieve what you want using sass as you need to know your bottom color in order to give the top color a value.

If you can't use rgba and don't know what your bottom color is, you could use a white transparent [10x10px](http://stevelove.org/2009/07/10/png-background-repeat-bug-in-internet-explorer-7-and-8/) png as a background. If you need IE6 support, use an [IE png fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/) or [filters](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) (not w3c compliant afaik).

```
.overlay {
    background: transparent url('transparent-white.png') repeat;
{
```

That being said, my humble opinion is that we should leave IE9< behind when talking about using rgba, it's just too messy to give them support, and not generally worth it.

EDIT:

You are using `$lightness` property with a value of 150%, while it only accepts values between 0% and 100%. If you use 0% you get the same color, while using 100% you get white. If background color is solid, you can use, as you said in your question, the scale_color function like this:

```
.scss {
    background-color:scale-color($background, $lightness:50%);
}
```

It will result in your background color but a 50% lighter. Basically you got all the job done but using 50% instead of 150% :)

Comment: When I say I don't know the value of the bottom color what I mean is that I don't want to have to know ahead of time. In other words, anyone could put in whatever value they wanted for the bottom color, and the SCSS function would correctly calculate the result of the transparency. I want to do this with SCSS, not images.

Comment: I updated the answer, you had mostly everything done in your question :P

Comment: Did you look at it on the jsFiddle? When I use 50% I see a completely different color, not just a different shade of the same color. Perhaps this is a bug with jsFiddle's implementation of SCSS.

Comment: I did, and I'm pretty sure scssYou can test it [here](http://sass-lang.com/try.html), the result is very different to jsFiddle's.

Comment: @scumah: The color you get with 50% is indeed different and much closer than the weird red, but it's still the wrong color if you're trying to imitate white with 50% opacity. It's a bright wintergreen color rather than a slightly greenish white.